# Review queues suggesting: review carefully because this post is identified as spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Sometime in the review queue I see the below message with some questions/answers:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

I understand the literal meaning of this.

But I am curious to know something more about it like from where it got generated or auto scheduled script provide this?

Here is one [example post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10780420).